# How would the Earth look without water in the oceans?

Tags: ocean, water, earth-observation, visualization

Has there ever been a movie, a documentary, or an image that provides a visualization of the oceans without water? I'm writing an article on geology and I thought a visual representation would be of great importance. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic due to insufficient research.

Comment: However, an lmgtfy link is a bit rude.

Comment: If there were no water ,you would not be here to wonder.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

National Geographic made a documentary called **Drain the Ocean**, this is [You Tube link to part one](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HVJNLSwCGHc). the other three parts are there as well.

Comment: That is a wonderful documentary!

Answer (score 4):

There is a YouTube clip [How the Earth Would Look Like Without Oceans](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2ythE-hJiNE), it is only 1 minute 34 seconds; however, it is very graphical with no commentary, but with information about features of the ocean basins, ridges (and even the location of the Titanic!).

Information presented also includes spreading rates and depths.

Comment: cool! and do me actually know _what_ is there below?